# How to send an array of Objects to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js

**Brief version**

I want to know how can I send below array of objects in NodeJS to an app in AngularJS.

```
var players = 
[ 
  Footer: { username: 'Footer', hp: 200, exp: 1 },
  Barter: { username: 'Barter', hp: 200, exp: 1 }
];
```

I've tried to send it in many ways, but I always receive an empty array on the AngularJS side.

**Extended question**

On the server, I'm assigning new users to an array `players`. I want to found the `user object` passing `username` as some index to the array. I've successfully done it using .push method, but it don't provide a way to access it with indexes. So, I've started to use the [bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) to create objects on my array and, later on, access then using this:

```
//players.push(user); //This does work, but won't be indexed.
var username = user.username; //This is the new user object.
players[username] = user; //Using bracket notation to create object
```

After that, I have a route that responds with this `players` array. I've tried both `res.send()` and `res.json()`. The array is being `console.log()` before sent and it is fine. But the response comes as an empty array.

On the client-side, I'm logging res.data, which just logs `[]`.

I'm kind of stuck in here. If needed be, I can put more code here. Or, you can access this [GitHub project](https://github.com/Rodmentou/InfinityRPG) with the full code.

Comment: They syntax your first array is wrong, you cannot have keys for array items

Comment: Thanks, @mcfedr . I have changed array to object and everything is working fine. Just [ ] to { }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `players` is an array, you have to use indices to fill it instead of `username` strings. `JSON.stringify` will ignore non-integer keys on array objects.